# Asynchronus-PHP Upload Huge csv data into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, csv, asynchronous

I tried to upload around 20k rows CSV into SQL using async method referring to this post :

[How to import a huge CSV file with 200,00 rows to MySQL (asynchronous and fast)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32504778/how-to-import-huge-csv-file-with-200-00-rows-to-mysql-asynchronous-and-fast)

The script already running and success when I upload 10000 data, but when I checked into the database, I found that **only half rows (5000 rows) were Inserted**. 
I've tried to change the $batchsize from 1000 to 100, only 9400rows inserted instead of supposedly 10000 rows

here's my current code :

**index.php :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>csv upload</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="csv" value="" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**upload.php :**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>

<script>
//Declaration of function that will insert data into database
 function senddata(filename){
        var file = filename;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "senddata.php",
            data: {file},
            async: true,
            success: function(html){
                $("#result").html(html);
            }
        })
        }
</script>

<?php

$batchsize = 100; //split huge CSV file by 1,000, you can modify this based on your needs

if($_FILES['csv']['error'] == 0){

    $name = $_FILES['csv']['name'];
    $ext = explode(".", $name);
    $ext = $ext[1];
    $tmpName = $_FILES['csv']['tmp_name'];

    if($ext === 'csv'){ //check if uploaded file is of CSV format

        if(($handle = fopen($tmpName, 'r')) !== FALSE) {

            set_time_limit(0);
            $row = 0;

            while(($data = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) {

                //splitting of CSV file :
                if ($row % $batchsize == 0):

                    $file = fopen("minpoints$row.csv","w");

                endif;

                $csv[$row]['col1'] = $data[0];
                $csv[$row]['col2'] = $data[1];
                $min = $data[0];
                $points = $data[1];
                $json = "'$min', '$points'";
                fwrite($file,$json.PHP_EOL);

                //sending the splitted CSV files, batch by batch...
                if ($row % $batchsize == 0):

                    echo "<script> senddata('minpoints$row.csv'); </script>";

                endif;
                $row++;

            }

            fclose($file);
            fclose($handle);

        }
    } else {

        echo "Only CSV files are allowed.";

    }
    //alert once done.
    echo "<script> alert('CSV imported!') </script>";
} ?>
```

**senddata.php :**

```
<?php
include('config.php');
$data = $_POST['file'];
$handle = fopen($data, "r");
$test = file_get_contents($data);
// print_r($test);die;
if ($handle) {
    $counter = 0;
    //instead of executing query one by one,
    //let us prepare 1 SQL query that will insert all values from the batch
    $sql ="INSERT INTO table_test(name,contact_number) VALUES ";
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
      $sql .= "($line),";
      $counter++;
    }
    $sql = substr($sql, 0, strlen($sql) - 1);
     if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    } else {
    }
    fclose($handle);
} else {  
} 
//unlink CSV file once already imported to DB to clear directory
unlink($data);
?>
```

> My Goals are :

1. Upload huge csv data asynchronusly with complete data
2. To understand this codes :
   --> fwrite($file,$json.PHP_EOL); and
   -->  senddata('minpoints$row.csv'); ;

Comment: How big is your file, and what's the maximum file size given by upload_max_filesize in php.ini?

Comment: 10000 rows (507KB)
upload_max_filesize = 40M

Comment: Have you tried catching any error?

Comment: Maybe the table `table_test` has an **NOT NULL** column and the `csv` has **NULL** at some case and that's why is not inserted?

Comment: @DannyThunder do you mean error while uploading ? I haven't got any error msg during upload process,

Comment: @Roy thanks man !!! its the problem, the csv containing NULL, after i cleaned it up it's successfully uploaded ! problem solved, but the csv might contain NULL according to the user, how to anticipate it ? do i have to change the table_test structure table ?

Comment: @owf Yes, make `name` and `contact_number` **NULL**, with `ALTER TABLE table_test MODIFY name your-type(your-number);` _Columns are nullable by default. As long as the column is not declared UNIQUE or NOT NULL, there shouldn't be any problems._

Comment: @Roy thank you, after i changed the structure table, it works perfectly. Anyway do you have an idea how to skip the first row (header) ? I've tried to use IF the $counter > 0 on senddata.php , but it skips every first counter of each batch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using this you can skip the just first row of CSV file (header of CSV file) . try that

```
 while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            if ($_POST['file'] == 'minpoints0.csv' && $counter > 0) {
                $sql .= "('$line'),";
            }
            $counter++;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The table `table_test` has an NOT NULL column and the csv has `NULL` values at some case and that's why is not inserted.

You can make `name` and `contact_number` **NULL**, with 

`ALTER TABLE table_test MODIFY name your-type(your-number);` 
*Columns are nullable by default. As long as the column is not declared UNIQUE or NOT NULL, there shouldn't be any problems.*

> @owf: - thank you, after i changed the structure table, it works
>   perfectly. Anyway do you have an idea how to skip the first row
>   (header) ? I've tried to use IF the $counter > 0 on senddata.php , but
>   it skips every first counter of each batch

**R**:

First for all, you need to `$flag` the first parsed **csv** to know that it comes with the first row to be skipped.
Add a variable to the `ajax` that check if is the first **csv** registered.
So, en `ajax.php` you know if the **csv** is the first one or not, based in this method, you can skip the first row of the first batched **csv**

Comment: yes, i've tried that way 

while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
     if($counter>0){ //should work here.
      $sql .= "($line),";
     }
      $counter++;
    }

but, it will skips every first row of each batch